# X509Store как добавить сертификат не из кода

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Подскажите, как **НЕ** из кода средствами dotnet либо еще как то можно добавить сертификат в x509Store ?

Иначе говоря, есть ли команда dotnet плагин наподобие "dotnet_ef" через который можно было бы добавить сертификат ? В настоящий момент, я использую приведенный ниже код, однако для моих целей он избыточен.

```
using var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlag.ReadWrite);
var cert = new X509Certificate2("path to cert");
store.Add(cert) ;
```

**UPD:**

- Ручные и полу-ручные варианты не интересуют, нужно именно команда
  которую можно будет автоматизировать скриптом.
- Целевая ОС - линукс

На текущий момент нашел вот [такой](https://github.com/stylianosnicoletti/dotnet-certificate-tool) вариант, однако хочется узнать возможно есть что то готовое от Microsoft, а не опен сорс

Comment: [Import-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/import-certificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps), [Import-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/import-pfxcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: @Vasek Целевая ОС - линукс, варианты для разработки так же не подходят,

Comment: Шелл-скрипт что-ли нужен, тогда зачем метка C# на вопросе?

Comment: У сишарпа какой из линуксовых x509?  Их тут и без сишарпа около 5